# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' occurs when finding common key value pairs between two dictionaries

Tags: python

I have written a code where I find common key-value pairs between two dictionaries as given below:

```
d_inter = dict(set(message.iteritems()).intersection(v.iteritems()))
```

This works fine but when `message` dictionaries has a `key` whose value is of type `list`, I get an error as `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

I read a couple of answers related to this and found out that this error occurs when we try to use `list` as a `key` in any dictionary but here I am not doing anything like that. Please help me fix this.

Comment: `message` can't have a list key - the problem would have come up when you tried to put that key into `message`.

Comment: "this error occurs when we try to use `list` as a `key` in any dictionary but here I am not doing anything like that" - but you just said you had a list key in the previous sentence.

Comment: @user2357112: Thank you for your constructive answers which are very helpful. But I said "has a key whose value is of type list" and not "has a key of type list".

Comment: Oh. Then it's because you try to create a `set` with an unhashable tuple in it. Tuples are only hashable if all their elements are hashable, and if one of your values is unhashable, the corresponding key-value pair tuple is unhashable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `list()` items are not hashable. The `hash()` method is used for generating `dict()` keys.

A solution can be to convert your lists to tuples, but you cannot use lists in a dict like this.

Example with lists:

```
{[1]: 1, [2]: 2}
```

Result:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Example with lists converted to tuples:

```
{tuple([1]): 1, tuple([2]): 2}
```

Result:

```
{(1,): 1, (2,): 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the exact same reason that a `list` cannot be a key in a `dict`, it cannot be an element of a `set`. They work the same way internally; the only real difference is that a set does not "map" its "keys" to any corresponding values.